# where can one find old patches/curated versions of ffmpeg for qsv (mpeg2_qsv)?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-2, intel-media-sdk

for the past year or so the mpeg2_qsv encoder in ffmpeg/libmfx has been broken due to a idr interval problem (sends only one idr frame at the start of the video rather than sending idr frames at a certain interval) i have found a solution/workaround by adding the idr-interval option defined in h264_qsv.c to the mpeg2_qsv.c provided in ffmpeg it does work but the quality of the output is subpar even after applying heavy post processing filters and i have been working on this exact platform for the past 4 years so i know for a fact that it used to work way better hence i have been trying to revert the changes made to ffmpeg in the past 1-2 years unsuccessfully as i am not able to find old patches that i could use as reference.

i understand that for this problem a lot of people suggest using ffmpeg 2.8 which apparently is the best for old qsv behaviour but due to mediasdk version mismatches i haven't been able to build it successfully on any new OS after ubuntu 18.04 but i cannot use ubuntu 18.04 or below because of a hardware issue on my platform which messes with the xserver introducing a lot of weird errors if anyone has any suggestions of how i can overcome this then please help as i am all ears

i am new to this website so i apologize in advance if i have made a mistake in asking this question.

thank you for your patience and guidance

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: From the link you provided "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it" i did describe the problem and ask for a solution and not a tool what did I do wrong?